# H2: Insert is slow because of index on column

Tags: hash, indexing, h2

I am using the h2 database to store data.
Each record has to be unique in the database (unique in the sense that the combination of timestamp, name, message,.. doesn't appear twice in the table). Therefore one column in the table is the hash of the data in the record. To speed up searching if the record already exists I created an index on the hash column. Indeed searching for a record with given hash is very fast.
But here is the problem: While in the beginning insertion of 10k records is fast enough (takes about a second), it gets awefully slow when having already one million records in the database (takes a minute). This probably because the new hashes need to be integrated into the existing index b-tree.

Is there any way to speed this up or is there a better way to ensure uniqueness of data records in the table?

Edit: To be more concrete:
Let's say my records are transactions which have the following fields:

time stamp, type, sender recipient, amount, message

A transaction should only appear once in the table so before inserting a new transaction I have to check if the transaction is already in the table. Since the sha 256 hash of all fields is unique my idea was to add a column 'hash' to the table where the hash of the fields is put in. Before inserting a new record I calculate the hash of the fields and query the table for the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Index has its own over head. If you have a table where you will be having lots of insertions, I would suggest to avoid indexing on it as it has over-head of hash.

May I know what do you mean by --> one column in the table is the hash of the data in the record??

You can create a unique key constraint (here it will be the composite key of all those 3 mentioned columns), Let me know the requirements, may be we can give you a better solution of doing it in a simpler way :)

Danyal

Answer (score 0):

Man, this is probably not a good way to query all the records, check them for duplicates and then insert the new row :). As soon as you move ahead, the overhead will increase as the number of the records increase.

Create a unique key constraint (check http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html ) on the combination of these field, you don't need to compute the hash, database will handle the hash thing. Just try to add the duplicate record, you will get the exception, catch the exception and show the error message as duplicate insertion..

Once you create the unique index, it won't allow you to insert any duplicate records. It is pretty secure and safe.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Seems I have to elaborate a bit more:

Comment: When i get a new transaction it should not be inserted immeadiately into the table. Rather it should be checked if it is new and if that is the case it is sent to other interested parties. After a certain amount of time the batch of new transactions is inserted into the database.

Comment: I understand it but that will be a very huge operation, I guess, doing an immediate insert and catching the exception would be faster and more feasible here rather than loading all the records and then performing computation on application layer..

Answer (score 0):

Indexing randomly distributed data is bad for performance. Once there are more entries in the index than fit in the cache, then updating the index will get very slow, specially when using a hard disk. This is because seeks on a hard disk are very slow. This, in combination with the random distribution of the data, will lead to very bad performance. With solid state disks it's a bit better, because random access reads are faster there.

Comment: Actually I don't see any reads when looking at the resource manager, just tons of writes. Is this just a problem of the H2 database or a gnereal problem that **all** databases share? There are databases which contain millions of hashes, how do they search for a given hash?

Comment: They usually try to keep all the hashes in memory. Otherwise, basically each access results in at least one disk read operation, as there is no locality with hashes. As for writes, it is possible in theory to reduce them by using a log structured storage; but H2 is not yet optimized for this case (except when creating an index after adding the data; this case should be OK). In any case, I would avoid indexing randomly distributed data.

Comment: Update: I switched H2 from 1.3.175 to 1.4.182. This solved the problem, inserting new rows is a **lot** faster with lower hard disk activity.